# CQRS Task UI - Responding to underlying changes

Tags: user-interface, cqrs

Been moving into some task oriented UI as a part of my CQRS implementation.

The problem is I have come across the need to update additional properties in my UI as a result of a change made by an initial command sent from the same UI.

My case is different but here's an example...
eg. **CommandA Add item to cart** resulted in the following events (which all need to be reflected on the UI)

- change to store inventory
- add item to shopping cart
- change total with sales tax

What's the best way to handle this without baking my business logic into my UI?

- return a list of resulting events that were performed as a result to the initial command?
- return a DTO that reflects changes
- other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have queries - not commands - on your hands.

Comment: What happens - business wise - when I order an item that's out of stock? You're not gonna sell it to me? I assume if the product is somehow discontinued (not available for back order) you can't, but that's hardly the common case, now is it? #reflectionwhilerereadingyourquestion

Comment: Calculating sales tax sounds like a reusable lib that can be used both server and clientside if it's the same tech. Client could also query the lib using some sort of remote facade without mutating state of the system.

Comment: I need commands as I need to persist values. However, our users must make decisions based on calculated values in our BL. Maybe to clarify, my situation is like making many calculations similar to sales tax, and resulting calculations because of those calculations. 

For long running processes I agree a query needs to be made. Not meaning to play devil's advocate but the devil is always in the details (common/uncommon). For short running commands your solution means I need to perform a command and query not guaranteed to have reached persistence at that point or server call per calc.

Comment: You're making no sense ... If an end-user makes decision based on calculated values than that's a query. If you want to store the result of a calculation as part of a command the spectrum shifts towards "do I trust the command issued with the calculated data in it". What's the motivation for doing the calculation during the handling of the command vs. as a query of which the results get stuffed in the command and persisted eventually?

Comment: Because in our case queries are separate from our persistence. We cannot wait for our changes to replicate to all of our scalable servers for a reliable query.

Comment: I would presume salestax calculation does not require persistence. As such, try to find the canonical input model for calculating sales tax, create a component that calculates sales tax based on this model and share it between the command processing and UI.

Comment: The solution we went with we based on whether the user is subscribed to changes. It is similar to this solution but without the additional web request( or web requests as we have literally hundreds of these calculations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't completed it yet, but my idea is to use a Hub from the SignalR framework and subscribe to events and act on them. As long as you can correlate user guids with the connected user guids in SignalR, you can send updates to the correct client and even detect if they still are there.

SignalR isn't that mature yet but the tests I have done works pretty good.

I use it with Knockoutjs and I just update my view models and call functions.

Comment: So you notify the web client when your event has been processed and persisted as the next version of the aggregate?

Comment: Given that you can make the SignalR Hub/Persistent connection subscribe to events, you could call Javascript functions on the correct client when a message arrives. That is my plan anyway. 
Say you add an item to the cart which triggers a discount or something, you could probably subscribe to the corrected total amount message and update that client with the updated data.

Comment: Ok I've put together a solution. We created a change notifications subscription where you can tell the subscription what DTO was returned (so you can return the resulting changes specific to the user). If the change process is long running we can use a push library (web sockets or other) to notify the client when the changes are complete. If it's short running the changes are made and persisted to the event, then result DTO is created and returned to the user. Thanks for the input, it really helped get me on track.

Answer (score 1):

Do those events really need to be reflected in the UI?  Consider Amazon, who display "you just added foo to your cart", but don't show any of those other details.  That might save you from the problem by redefining it away.

Otherwise, why are you afraid of business logic in the "UI" - specifically, why not include some components from the service that owns each part of that system in your client, and give them the responsibility of doing whatever local updates are appropriate?

In other words, having part of the logic from your sales tax service running in the UI is fine.  You (obviously) don't trust it with the billing calculations for tax, but you can totally trust it to do the right thing for the client.

The other advantage of that model is that you get instant feedback for the user, or at least the option of showing instant feedback, *without* baking more business process knowledge into the client.

For example, recalculating shipping takes time to do - if your client shows a spinner over that, something needs to know to trigger that showing up, right?

If your UI knows that, it has embedded business process around the process.  On the other hand, if you have code that is part of the "shipping" service, you can change what response occurs in the client by changing only the one service...

Comment: The shopping cart was just an example and with my scenarios I will have to post changes that are committed. And baking BL into the UI means that you would have to load modules covering scope of an entire entity instead of the DTO (this is going to get scary for our case and many many others). 

We have determined that there are long running processes where a round trip to the server would be difficult unless using a solution similar Mikael Östberg's posted here. I'm in the process of getting a solution ready to post whereby the user can choose to subscribe to changes if available.